# Sending Notification To IOS And Android using Google Cloud Messaging in PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to both ios and android from my php server. I didn't get any proper documentation for sending notifications to ios via google cloud messaging. Could you please me in integrating this.

Comment: @Johnny Could you please provide me some code or any link.

Comment: have you checked [this document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Comment: @RahulTiwari I like to know whether google will take care of the device(whether it is android or ios) or we need to send separate calls for ios and android.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server) there is no changes in the server.

Comment: @RahulTiwari Could you please help me with some php code to achieve this.

Comment: @arjunarjun, you should post your php code or curl format HTTP request in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link for the API it provides (HTTP will fit you the best)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-http-server-protocol

And check this one for some examples on how to send to different devices, devices groups etc.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Besides this, you gonna need to set up the the mobile apps in Firebase Console
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist